# spring cloud dataflow list job executions by name with wildcard supported?

Tags: spring, list, cloud, jobs, dataflow

This is the API in question:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#api-guide-resources-job-executions-list-by-name.

It seems this cannot have wildcards in the name.  Is this true?

So I have many job executions with the name "matchSimulationJob" and hence this API works:  GET on http://localhost:9393/jobs/executions?name=matchSimulationJob

But I also have jobs that all have the same prefix, as in:
matchSimulationJob*timestamp*  where *timestamp* is the suffix for the actual timestamp.  Basically, I want to list all job executions that start with this specific prefix of "matchSimulationJob."  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

We currently don't support wildcard searches for job executions by jobName via the RESTful API.  However you can add a issue requesting the feature [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues).